# Creating an encryption program with a choice of three methods! It has issues I am not sure how to fix

Tags: c++, encryption

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int get_ascii_int(char ch);
int get_offset_ascii(char ch2, int offset);
//int print_string_ints(string test_string);
int method3_substitution_abc();

//above are the function declarations

int main()
{
    string test_string;//input of string
    char ch = 0;//used in method1
    char ch2 = 0;//used in method2
    int index1 = 0;//used in for loop method1
    int index2 = 0;//used in for loop method2
    int offset = 0;//input of how much to offset
    int new_ascii = 0;//the new ascii with offset
    int ascii_value1 = 0;//the ascii value of the char
    int option;//the menu choice of encryption method
    int decision;//the decision to save or display
    ofstream method1;//method 1 text file
    ofstream method2;//method 2 text file
    ofstream method3;//method 3 text file
    string test_string_copy;//copy of string method 2

    //Below is a description of the methods of encryption
    cout << "There are three methods of encryption, listed below, to choose from: " << endl;
    cout << "1. Converting characters into the corresponding ASCII values. " << endl;
    cout << "2. Shifting characters right/left using the ASCII value of the characters ";
    cout << "and a set offset amount. " << endl;
    cout << "3. Using a reverse alphabet, so each letter will be replaced with the letter ";
    cout << "on the opposite end of the alphabet. For example, A would become Z. " << endl;

    cout << "Which encryption method would you like to use, 1, 2, 3? ";
    cin >> option;

    switch (option)
    {
    case '1':
        method1.open("method1.txt");


        cout << "Input a word or name: ";
        getline(cin, test_string);

        for (; index1 < test_string.size(); index1++);
        {
            ascii_value1 = get_ascii_int(test_string[index1]);
        }
        cout << "Would you like to display the file or save it, enter 1 for display or 2 for save?";
        cin >> decision;

        if (decision == '1')
        {
            cout << "The encrypted code is " << ascii_value1 << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            if (method1.is_open())
            {
                method1 << "The encrpyted code is " << ascii_value1 << endl;
                method1.close();
            }
            else
                cout << "Unable to open file." << endl;
        }
        break;

    case '2':
        method2.open("method2.txt");

        cout << "Input a word or name: ";
        getline(cin, test_string);
        test_string_copy = test_string;

        for (; index2 < test_string_copy.size(); index2++);
        {
            new_ascii = get_offset_ascii(test_string_copy[index2], ch2);
        }
        cout << "Would you like to display the file or save it, enter 1 for display or 2 for save?";
        cin >> decision;

        if (decision == '1')
        {
            cout << "The encrypted code is " << new_ascii << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            if (method2.is_open())
            {
                method2 << "The encrypted code is " << new_ascii << endl;
                method2.close();
            }
            else
                cout << "Unable to open file." << endl;
        }
        break;

    case '3':
        method3.open("method3.txt");

        method3_substitution_abc();

        break;
    }

    return 0;
}

//listed below are the function definitions

int get_ascii_int(char ch)
{
    return ((int)ch);
}

int get_offset_ascii(char ch2, int offset)
{
    int new_offset_value;//the value after adding the determined offset to the ascii value of the letter
    new_offset_value = (int)ch2 + offset;
    (char)new_offset_value;

    return (new_offset_value);
}

//int print_string_ints(string test_string)
//{
//for (int i = 0; i < test_string.size(); i++)
//{
//(int)test_string[i++];
//}
//return 0;
//}

int method3_substitution_abc()
{
    char test_string[100];
    cout << "Enter a name or phrase: ";
    cin >> test_string;

    if (isupper((int)test_string))
    {
        int stalpha = 65;//start of alphabet
        int endalpha = 90;//end of alphabet
        char b[100];//array to reverse the alphabet
        for (int i = 0; test_string[i] != '\0'; i++)
        {
            b[i] = endalpha - (test_string[i] - 65);
        }
    }
    else if (islower((int)test_string))
        int stalpha = 97;//start of alphabet
    int endalpha = 122;//end of alphabet
    char b[100];//array to reverse the alphabet
    for (int i = 0; test_string[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        b[i] = endalpha - (test_string[i] - 97);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to write this encryption program. And I am just getting really confused on why it won't run.

For example the switch statement is not running correctly, it will go to the correct case and then skip the input of the string?

This is my first experience with C++ so I struggle to debug.

I am having issues with saving the file to a text file after the user chooses to save or display? It has to be done after every case in the switch statement.

I also know the for loops I am using are not correct for method 1 and 2? Could someone check those out and tell me what the issue is. I am pretty sure it has to do with the parameters for the for loop.

And I don't know if I should use a string or an array for this? (In the part where the user inputs a string

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In order for us to help you, it is best to present a clear, concise question on a particular issue you are having. Not an overall 'it's not working'. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer  Also be more specific on the actual nature of the issue (any errors, what isn't working, etc.)

Comment: Thank you I tried to be more clear in my questions. is that better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least the first problem you've identified (with the `switch` statement) is pretty simple and clear.

You've defined `option` as an `int`, so when you read it it's read as an integer. That means if the user enters `1`, it'll have the value `1`, which is different from the value `'1'`. `'1'` is a character that will (for example) print as `1`, but its value is actually 49 in most character sets.

You have two obvious choices: either change `option` to be a `char`, so it'll be read as a character instead of an integer, or else change the values in the switch statement from `'1'`, `'2'`, etc., to just `1`, `2`, etc.

At a guess, the problem you're seeing from getline is a fairly common one when you mix a string extractor (e.g., `cin >> my_string;`) with `std::getline`. The string extractor extracts a string from the stream, but leaves the `new-line` character in the stream buffer. Then when you call `std::getline`, it reads that new-line as an empty string, so it doesn't wait for you to enter more input.

If you really have to mix the two this way, you probably want to add a call to `std::cin.ignore` to read and ignore any data up to and including the new-line character. Then when you call `std::getline`, it'll actually read some data.

Comment: Could you look into the getline(cin,test_string) this part is not running right? @jerrycoffin

Comment: @amg2015: You haven't described what you want well enough to really say much (if anything) about that.

Comment: Okay, sorry I guess I don't understand why we can't use cin >> with a string and why we have to use the getline. Then when I try and use the getline it skips over the input and doesnt let me enter anything @jerrycoffin